# Remove class from all element on webpage

Tags: javascript

I am beginner web developer.
I have small problem with remove class from all elements on my webpage.

I have this code:

```
showErrorMessage(message, className) {
      let elems = document.querySelectorAll("text-danger invalid");
      [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove("text-danger invalid");
      });

      document.querySelector(className).className += " text-danger invalid";
      Swal.fire(
        'Błąd',
        message,
        'error',
      );
    },
```

This code work fine, but not remove old class from div. I need:

1. Remove from all elements on my webpage this class: text-danger invalid
2. add class to selected element
3. show message Swal

I have problem with 1.

How can I repair it?

Please help me :)

Comment: It's always worth reviewing the available documentation for the functions you're using, in this case [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (and `querySelector`) and [`classList.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove). What you're passing to `querySelectorAll` isn't a class selector, and `remove` doesn't accept a space-delimited list.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues with your code:

1. There's an issue with your selector passed in line 2. As Ivan suggest below:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".text-danger.invalid");
```

2. `element.classList.remove()` accepts classes as separate strings ([see the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove)). Replace line 4 with:

```
el.classList.remove("text-danger", "invalid");
```

EDIT: Incorporated the suggestions from below comments

Comment: Then there's the issue with the selector being passed to `querySelectorAll` (and `querySelector`)...

Comment: I have this code: showErrorMessage(message, className) {
      let elems = document.querySelectorAll("text-danger.invalid");
      [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove("text-danger", "invalid");
      });

      document.querySelector(className).className += " text-danger invalid";
      Swal.fire(
        'Błąd',
        message,
        'error',
      );
    }, and it's not working. Not remove class https://ibb.co/0JV5FnG

Comment: Sorry. I had a typo in my comment. It should be `(".text-danger.invalid")` with a dot at the beginning. I deleted the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues with your code:

1. `querySelectorAll()` uses CSS selectors. So if you need to choose all elements with two classes, you need to use `".class-one.class-two"`.
2. `classList.remove()` does not allow spaces, so separate classes with a comma.
3. You can simplify your `forEach()`.

So here is the code that should work:

```
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".text-danger.invalid")

  elems.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove("text-danger", "invalid")
  })
```

See also the code snippet

```js
function remove() {
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".text-danger.invalid")
  elems.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove("text-danger", "invalid")
  })
}
```

```css
.text-danger.invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-danger invalid">Text</div>
<div class="text-danger invalid">Text</div>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove classes</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

`querySelectorAll` is `array-like`, is not `array`

Use `Array.from` for convert it to `array`

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll("text-danger invalid");

Array.from(elems).forEach(e => {
    e.classList.remove("text-danger", "invalid");
});
```

**Notice: Separate classes in `classList.remove`**